# Iterate through columns in dataframe and check the dtype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, etl

- This is for Python 2.7
  I have a large number of dataframes in my script that I am trying through iterate/loop through to determine the dtype of the column. From there, I would like to alter the column if it falls under a specific dtype (string, float, integer, boolean, list, date) for each dtype. For example, if one column is a "float", I would like to convert it to an int or string to strip the trailing zero(.0).

example dataframe:

```
df:
A     B     C     D
3.0  NaN   Apple  False
4.0  False Banana True
2.0  NaN   NaN    NaN
```

example of how I currently convert these on an individual case:

```
if 'A' in df:
    print(df['A'].dtype)
    >>> dtype('int64')
    df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
    print(df['A'].dtype)
    >>> dtype('O')
    df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip(".0")
```

The above method is not efficient as it only works for individual columns. I would love to just have something loop through the dataframe and do this, as this is difficult to do for 100 dataframes that contain 50-100 columns each.

How I imagined this happening:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import *

for col in df.columns:
    if col.dtype == 'int':
         # *do the above column manipulation*
         col = col.astype(str)
         col = col.str.strip(".0")
    elif col.dtype == 'str':
         # strip the zero
         col = col.str.strip(".0")
    elif col.dtype == 'date':
         # col = col.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    elif col.dtype == 'bool':
         # bool
    else:
        print('all done?')

OR

for col in df.columns:
    if col.dtype == np.int64:
       # do the data maniuplation
    elif (rest of the dtype manipulations)
```

Any help on how to convert these columns based on what dtype they are would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: you want to change the dtype of a column? `df.astype({'col1': 'int32'})` ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the dtype of the column but I cannot just do this for individual columns as there are 80,000 different types. Would be much better to iterate through. @Dorian

Comment: it's much faster and much cleaner if you just cast the whole column into the desired type. This is what you are doing anyways isn't it?

Comment: Writing 80,000 unique lines sounds ideal, you're right. @Dorian

Comment: 80'000 different types of what? of rows in you columns? are there 80'000 columns? than apply it on every column in a loop.

Comment: if there is a way you can give us explainatory data, then please give a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)